PSTricks figures interfering with one another under lualatex
I have an MWE that shows an interferance of one figure with another, if processed under lualatex:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pst-ode}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\psset{xunit=0.55cm,yunit=0.55cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-6)(16.5,6.75)
\psbezier[linewidth=0.75pt,linestyle=dashed](16.3,3.1)(10.6,2.98)(10.6,-3.18)(7.6,-4.86)(4.6,-6.54)(0.0,-4.5)(0.5,-1.64)(1.1,1.3)(5.6,2.54)(7.8,6.54)
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\psset{xunit=0.45cm,yunit=0.45cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-17,-2.25)(5.75,7.85)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\color{darkgray}\scriptstyle,linecolor=darkgray,linewidth=0.75pt,tickcolor=darkgray,Dx=3,Dy=2]{<->}(0,0)(-17,-2)(5,7)[\textcolor{darkgray}{$t$},0][\textcolor{darkgray}{$x$},90]
\pstODEsolve[algebraic]{TY}{(t) 0}{-15}{3}{200}{0 1}{y[1]|t*y[0]}
\listplot[plotstyle=line,linecolor=blue]{TY}
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

If processed with the sequence:
latex file.tex
dvips -o file.ps file.dvi
ps2pdf file.ps

it produces the expected image:

But when processed with lualatex, somehow the first picture interferes with the second and the graph shoots out of bounds, crossing the other figure and continuing.

Commenting any part of the first figure, allows it to processed correctly.
One other observation is that it has nothing to do with the fact of being close to one another -- even with pages of text in between the two, the problem persists.
EDITED and ADDED on Fri 20 Dec 2024:
After receiving the patch below from user @user187802, the figure processed properly and produced the same result as in the latex and xelatex workflow. BUT, but, when inserted in the original document -- along with many other figures -- it showed another incompatibility with a different figure, some five chapter before.
Here is the MWE with that new incompatibility:
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-ode}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

% Fix from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/733237/pstricks-figures-interfering-with-one-another-under-lualatex
\makeatletter
\def\psbezier@ii{%
    \addto@pscode{
        10 dict begin
        \ifPst@noCurrentPoint\else\pst@cp\fi
        \ifshowpoints true \else false \fi
        \ifx\pslinestyle\psls@@symbol \psls@symbol OpenSymbolBezier
        \else
        \tx@OpenBezier
        \ifshowpoints \tx@BezierShowPoints \fi
        \fi
        end
    }%
    \def\pst@linetype{1}%
    \ifx\pslinestyle\psls@@symbol\def\pslinestyle{none}\fi
  \end@OpenObj}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\newrgbcolor{xdxdff}{0.2 0.3 0.75}
\psset{xunit=1.5cm,yunit=1.5cm,Alpha=35,Beta=20}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(2,2)
\parametricplotThreeD[xPlotpoints=20,yPlotpoints=20,linewidth=0.5pt,linecolor=xdxdff](0.5,1.5)(0,360)
{t u cos mul
t u sin mul
0}
\pstThreeDPut(1,0.5,1.5){$\rho_n$}
\pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-2,xMax=2,yMin=-2,yMax=2,zMin=-1,zMax=2]
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\psset{xunit=0.45cm,yunit=0.45cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-17,-2.25)(5.75,7.85)
%\psframe(-17,-2.25)(5.75,7.85)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\color{darkgray}\scriptstyle,linecolor=darkgray,linewidth=0.75pt,tickcolor=darkgray,Dx=3,Dy=2]{<->}(0,0)(-17,-2)(5,7)[\textcolor{darkgray}{$t$},0][\textcolor{darkgray}{$x$},90]
\pstODEsolve[algebraic]{TY}{(t) 0}{-15}{3}{200}{0 1}{y[1]|t*y[0]}
\listplot[plotstyle=line,linecolor=blue]{TY}
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


The ODE to be solved is stiff, perhaps. Floating point operations in luapstricks and Ghostscript are double and single precision, respectively. This may lead to different results in case of stiff ODEs. Though I would expect the results to be the other way  around. Did you try solving the ODE using another tool, Octave or Matlab for example?

@AlexG I guess that possibility is ruled out because if you comment the frst figure on the MWE, lualatex goes on to solve the equation with no problems.

As a quick fix, you can move \pstODEsolve... into the first figure environment, before the \psbesier... command.

Alternatively, \AtBeginDvi{\pstODEsolve...} into the document preamble.

@AlexG I am not sure I understand what you are proposing. The first figure does not have and ODE to be solved. Would you write this into a full solution?

it is a bug in luapstricks.lua. Have to investigate ...

Here is a fix for lualatex (works also for the other engines) ...
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (format=lualatex 2024.12.1)  20 DEC 2024 16:19
 system commands enabled.
[...]


\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pst-ode}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\makeatletter
\def\psbezier@ii{%
    \addto@pscode{
        10 dict begin
        \ifPst@noCurrentPoint\else\pst@cp\fi
        \ifshowpoints true \else false \fi
        \ifx\pslinestyle\psls@@symbol \psls@symbol OpenSymbolBezier 
        \else 
        \tx@OpenBezier 
        \ifshowpoints \tx@BezierShowPoints \fi
        \fi
        end
    }%
    \def\pst@linetype{1}%
    \ifx\pslinestyle\psls@@symbol\def\pslinestyle{none}\fi
  \end@OpenObj}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \psset{xunit=0.55cm,yunit=0.55cm}
        \begin{pspicture}(0,-6)(16.5,6.75)
            \psbezier[linewidth=0.75pt,linestyle=dashed](16.3,3.1)(10.6,2.98)(10.6,-3.18)(7.6,-4.86)(4.6,-6.54)(0.0,-4.5)(0.5,-1.64)(1.1,1.3)(5.6,2.54)(7.8,6.54)
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{figure}
    
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \psset{xunit=0.45cm,yunit=0.45cm}
        \begin{pspicture}(-17,-2.25)(5.75,7.85)
            \psaxes[labelFontSize=\color{darkgray}\scriptstyle,linecolor=darkgray,linewidth=0.75pt,tickcolor=darkgray,Dx=3,Dy=2]{<->}(0,0)(-17,-2)(5,7)[\textcolor{darkgray}{$t$},0][\textcolor{darkgray}{$x$},90]
            \pstODEsolve[algebraic]{TY}{(t) 0}{-15}{3}{200}{0 1}{y[1]|t*y[0]}
            \listplot[plotstyle=line,linecolor=blue]{TY}
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}



It did fix the problem on this MWE that I posted, but it did NOT fix the probem on the larger file where the example come from, possibly because of other interactions with other figures on the file. It would really help if I could understand: where the error comes from ? luapstrics as mentioned by Alex Grahn? How the fix work? And how it would interact with larger files with more images?
I'll be working on a new MWE to see if the new problem is interaction with something else, meantime.

This new one was a hard MWE to obtain. The incompatibility, after I apply your patch, is with another figure (in my source) located some five chapters before. There is no space to place it here, so I'll edit the question with it. The behaviours is the same, it works fine with latex and xelatex workflow, but not with lualatex.

send me your file as private mail: hvoss@tug.org.  Try it also with these files: https://hvoss.org/tmp/pstricks.tex. and https://hvoss.org/tmp/pst-3dplot.tex.    With these files you do not need the above patch. It is a problem with variable names which should be used local and not global.

The files you posted above resolved the majority of the cases I had. There are still a few left, some caused by this interference with one particular figure -- the presence of this one figure causes problems with the others. I have made an MWE with them and sent over to your email.
